# creating a output file when the output file exists in the path

Tags: python, python-2.5

How do I code in python the option that when the output file exists in the path, the output file will automatically be "originalname"+"_1" / "originalname"+"_2" and so on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
import os.path

def getnewfilename(filename):
    testfile = filename
    i = 0
    while os.path.exists(testfile):
        i += 1
        testfile = "%s_%s" % (testfile, i) 

    return testfile
```

This should generate

```
filename
filename_1
filename_2
```

if you use %s_%3i" you should get

```
filename
filename_001
filename_002
filename_003
```

which will then list alphabetically (but have problems when i>=1000)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-os.path.html)  to check if a file already exists. The rest is a simple loop that tries new filenames.

Answer (score 0):

isfile checks for the existence of a file and goes down simlinks as well; you can use the full filepath.

```
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    do_something()
```